# Will comfrey root sluff off too much growth if you mow it with grass?

Tags: comfrey

I've heard that comfrey will sluff off layers when you cut it. Will the root of a comfrey plant die back too much if you mow it whenever you mow the grass?

I have an apple tree that's not producing yet, so I thought I would plant some comfrey plants a couple feet from the base to help it collect the nutrients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst comfrey is good at getting nutrients out of the ground it is a vigorous plant and will compete with the apple tree for water and other nutrients. Not ideal whilst the tree is establishing. I would plant it elsewhere and then compost the leaves and use that to mulch around the base of the apple.

As for mowing, established comfrey (give it at least a growing season uncut) will tolerate *occasional* mowing. We have some on our field and it gets flailed a few times a year without any problems. If you are trying to maintain an ornamental lawn with a grass height of less than 50mm it will eventually die out.

Comment: I have no problem with water issues as the water creek is about 200 feet away, and 6 feet lower.

Comment: It might sound close to you, but remember until it has actually grown roots that far, it can't tap into that water and it will need water for those roots to grow. Most of a trees feeder roots are near(ish) the surface as they need more oxygen than anchoring roots which aren't as metabolically active. I wouldn't expect an apple to be producing feeder roots 6 feets down. If it is grafted, chances are its root system is a lot smaller than you expect, which is why keeping the base of the tree clear of competing plants is really important.